# Unable to set Assignee to second user task in activiti in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, activiti

I am new to activiti in spring boot. I have created the process i.e

Start---> User Task---> User Task---->End.

Now I have to assigned the dynamically Assignee to both user task. I have sent the Assignee to first user task by using this:

```
ProcessInstance process = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey('process', variables);

Task task = taskService.createTaskQuery().processInstanceId(process.getId()).singleResult();
task.setAssignee("charnjeet");
taskService.saveTask(task);
```

Now when I have completed the task from http://localhost:8080/activiti-explorer/ui/ then Listener, Service task expression is working. Can any one help me here. I want to assigned both user task to "charnjeet".

Answer (score 1):

Acitiviti will not list the next before completion of your task one, so you can't assign Task assignee before completion of TASK1

I came over this by using expression based assignee assignment

I defined a user task as

```
<userTask id="sid-42BAE58A-8FFB-4B02-AAED-E0D8EA5A7E39" name="Telephone interview" activiti:assignee="${taskAssingeeName}">
  <documentation>Conduct a telephone interview with ${applicant.name}. Phone number = ${applicant.phoneNumber}</documentation>
</userTask>
```

where **`activiti:assignee="${taskAssingeeName}"`** is added! this expression variable will set assignee dynamically
where **`taskAssingeeName`** is process variable

Answer (score 0):

These are some ways to save your time, to be used in XML as  `activiti:assignee="${assingee}"`:

1.) Create a start-form to select the `${assignee}`(a text field) who is going to get assigned for both of the task.

2.) Create an execution listener at end of each task to set `${assignee}` for next task.

3.) As explained by Mr. Arjun.